# Convert Null value retrieving from database into decimal data type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Please check the Table below:

[image: This is tblProfile]

Scope is: I have to check in the database the top **profileid** and have to increase it by 1. If no data is there then it will fetch **0** and will increase it by **1**.

I am getting the top value when there is data but in case the table is completely empty, I am getting exception. Code is as below.

```
        public Decimal GetTopProfileID()
        {
            Decimal topID = 0;
            var profileID = _dbContext.tblProfile.Max(n => n.profileid);
            try
            {
                if (profileID == null)
                {
                    topID = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    topID = Convert.ToDecimal(profileID);
                    topID++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return topID;
        }
```

Please help me find the solution. Ready for any question.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: First, get rid of the try/catch block - it's not doing you any good, but cluttering up your code. Secondly, what exception are you getting, and where? Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: `.Max()` will throw an exception if there are no items in the collection.

Comment: check out TryParse method instead

Comment: What is the reason for this. I hope you not trying to set the ID when trying to insert a new record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When there's no record in the table and you try to get **.Max()** value,
>   then it will throw an error, so its better to verify if any record
>   exist or not.

Update your code as follows.

```
if (_dbContext.tblProfile.Any()) {
    //Verify records in tblProfile table, if there's any record exist or not

    return Convert.ToDecimal(_dbContext.tblProfile.Max(n = > n.profileid)) + 1;
    try {
        if (profileID == null) {
            topID = 1;
        } else {
            topID = Convert.ToDecimal(profileID);
            topID++;
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }

    return topID;
} else { //If there's no value in table then assuming it should return 1.
    return 1;
}
```

**Update**

Or you can make it more simpler:

```
if (_dbContext.tblProfile.Any()) {
        //Verify records in tblProfile table, if there's any record exist or not

        return Convert.ToDecimal(_dbContext.tblProfile.Max(n = > n.profileid)) + 1;
    } else { //If there's no value in table then assuming it should return 1.
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if (_dbContext.tblProfile.Any()) 
{
   //Verify records in tblProfile table, if there's any record exist or not
   var profileID = _dbContext.tblProfile.Max(n = > n.profileid) ?? 0;    

   return profileID + 1;
} 
else 
  return 1;
```

Also if ProfileID is not nullable then don't need care about null value.

Then you can use below code:

```
return _dbContext.tblProfile.Any() ? _dbContext.tblProfile.Max(n = > n.profileid) + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: Max method can not return null as profileid is primary key. so you can eliminate it.

Comment: depends on type of profileId, if its nullable then can return null as well. So if it;s primary key so don't need to check with null at all

Answer (score 0):

```
          var profileID = _dbContext.tblProfile.OrderByDescending(n => n.profileid).FirstOrDefault();
  Decimal topID = 1;
                            if (profileID != null)
                            {
                             decimal.TryParse(profileID.ProfileId, out topID);
                             topID++;
                            }

                        return topID;
            }
```

Above answer by Moksh Shah is correct, but in that case we are hitting Data Base twice, 
I think this should produce the desired result.

Comment: You need to update slightly, `.FirstOrDefault();` will return object of `.tblProfile` not the `profileId`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will modify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LastOrDefault()` like this:

```
decimal variableName = Convert.ToDecimal(_dbContext.tblProfile.Select(x=> x.ProfileId).LastOrDefault() + 1);
```

Should work.

This is better than other solution as there is only one database call.